# Roblox if Statement not running

Tags: if-statement, lua, roblox

I was wondering if I could get some help with this small script I tested. 
For some reason, the `if` statement isn't executing, meaning the function won't run even if the value doesn't equal Rinzler. `charData` is a StringValue to be specific.

```
local charData = script.Parent.Data.CharacterData
local active = game.Workspace.Part

function change()
    if not charData.Value == "Rinzler" then
        charData.Value = "Rinzler"
        print("Character has changed to Rinzler.")
    end
end

active.Touched:Connect(change)
```

`"Character has changed to Rinzler"` isn't printing in the console no matter what I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here `if not charData.Value == "Rinzler"`

The `not` operator has higher priority than `==` in operator precedence list.
Update that code to:

```
function change()
    if charData.Value ~= "Rinzler" then
        charData.Value = "Rinzler"
        print("Character has changed to Rinzler.")
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Vlad for the answer!

Comment: @Starflyer Was this the answer to your question? If so, please mark it as "Accepted" so that he gets a reputation bonus for answering your question. (It will also give you a little too!)